# Drawing Graphics on a borderless form

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

This behavior in C# is bizarre.  I have the following class to allow me to effectively 'draw' on the desktop:

```
class drawOnDesktop {
    public static Form dodF = new Form();
    public static Graphics formGraphics;

    public drawOnDesktop() {
        formGraphics = dodF.CreateGraphics();
        dodF.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        dodF.TransparencyKey = Color.LightGreen;
        dodF.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        dodF.Location = new Point(0,0);
        dodF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        //dodF.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        dodF.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        dodF.MinimizeBox = false;
        dodF.MaximizeBox = false;
        dodF.ControlBox = false;
        //dodF.TopMost = true;  //For development in case something goes wrong
        dodF.BringToFront();
        dodF.Show();
    }

    public static void drawCircle(Point location) {
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, location.X, location.Y, 10, 10);
    }       
}
```

And I call it like this, from my main form:

```
drawOnDesktop dod = new drawOnDesktop();
drawOnDesktop.drawCircle(new Point(100,100));
```

If you run that code, you'll get a small black circle in the top left corner of your screen.  The problem is that you can see the form's border.  Now, try commenting out the `FormBorderStyle` line.  The black dot will appear for a fraction of a second, and disappear.  Why!?  As you can see, I've set a *lot* of properties on this form, and still it refuses to work.  Is it getting repainted over by the OS?

I don't need to worry about mouse events or things like that - the dots being placed on the screen are completely programmatic, and not from the user.  As well, if I set `dodF.ShowInTaskbar = false`, the entire program crashes.

How can I fix this code so the dot appears and stays until I `formGraphics.Clear(Color.Black)`?

Comment: **Never** use CreateGraphics(), whatever you draw will disappear without trace unpredictably whenever the window redraws itself.  Use the Paint event instead.  Use a bitmap if necessary to keep using your existing code.

Comment: Why do you use static `formGraphics` variable and `drawCircle` method, that are not really static as cannot be used until you call class constructor?

Comment: @mj82 honestly, I don't know.  It's the only way I can get it to work without getting an error.  formGraphics needs to be static, according to my compiler, but dodF doesn't, so I've removed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't keep a copy of the graphics around, that is just asking for trouble.  As others have stated, you should use the paint event to draw on the screen:

```
class drawOnDesktop
{
    public Form dodF = new Form();
    List<Point> circles = new List<Point>();
    public drawOnDesktop()
    {

        dodF.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        dodF.TransparencyKey = Color.LightGreen;
        dodF.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        dodF.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        dodF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        dodF.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        dodF.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        dodF.MinimizeBox = false;
        dodF.MaximizeBox = false;
        dodF.ControlBox = false;
        dodF.TopMost = true;  //For development in case something goes wrong
        dodF.BringToFront();
        dodF.Paint += dodF_Paint;
        dodF.Show();
    }

    void dodF_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = dodF.CreateGraphics())
        {
            foreach(Point location in circles)
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, location.X, location.Y, 10, 10);    
        }
    }

    public  void drawCircle(Point location)
    {
        circles.Add(location);
    }
}
```

You can call it the same way, but now every time the form repaints, it will redraw the circles.